# Notify user when question is answered

Tags: list, workflow, email, alert

I have a list for frequently asked questions that anybody can submit an item to. There already is a workflow set up to notify the approvers when an item is submitted so they can approve it. But, they also have the ability to answer the question without approving it.

I'm looking for a way to email the submitter of the item/question that their question has been answered. I know the individual user can add an alert to the list do notify them when anything they submit is changed, but is there a way to do that automatically?

I was thinking I could just add another workflow to do that, but I'm not sure which one I would need to use. They all look like they're asking for approvers, and I don't want the submitter to be able to approve the question! I just want them to know their question was answered.

Comment: I figured out how to make workflows in SharePoint Designer, so I feel like I may be getting closer but I'm still a little stuck. I have it set now where 
`If CurrentItem:Answer is not empty`
`Email these users`
But, that makes me force the email addresses in. I need to get the item creator's email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of SharePoint? If 2010 and you have a User Profile service you can follow something like [this](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/04/user-profile-data-in-sharepoint-designer-workflows/) - otherwise you may have to [write a custom workflow action](http://msmvps.com/blogs/sundar_narasiman/archive/2010/12/26/develop-custom-workflow-activity-for-sharepoint-2010-workflow.aspx) for SharePoint designer or use [some that already exist](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the links! I discovered that in the email window, there's a little address book next to the "To:" field that already lets you select "User who created current item". I guess I should have looked a little harder!

I getting an issue now where the email is failing, but I'll have to talk to the server admins about that more.

Comment: Turns out we have email turned off in our test environment. Emails worked great in production!